# r testthat and covr use in a non-package library

Tags: r, testthat, covr

I'd like to be able to use `testthat` and `covr` in a project that is **not** an r package.  In fact does not use any third party services.  Just a collection of plain-old-r source files

I am struggling to find out if this is possible, and if so, the instructions on how to set this is up.

What I have found assumes you are writing an r package.  I like to avoid this overhead.

**Prior Art:**

1. https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/covr-bringing-test-coverage-to-r/
2. https://walczak.org/2017/06/how-to-add-code-coverage-codecov-to-your-r-package/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That should be possible without problems.

**First**: I have one file with code that should be tested named `code.R`:

```
f1 <- function(n, ...) {
    rnorm(n = n, ...)
}
```

**Second**: Then I have a file with tests named `tests.R`:

```
source("code.R")

test_that("Random tests", {
    tmp1 <- f1(10)
    expect_type(tmp1, "double")
    expect_equal(length(tmp1), 10)
})
```

**Third**: And then you can run tests as well as coverage like this:

```
library(testthat)
library(covr)

test_file("tests.R")

res <- file_coverage("code.R", "tests.R")
res
report(res)
```

Multiple files should be no problem.